# Why "File not found" when using fileId of shared drive in google-api-services-drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

The code below is trying to grant a group `fileOrganizer` permission for a shared drive which I created earlier using similar code and the same service account impersonating the same user. (I've redacted the actual `DRIVE_ID` with a fake one)

```
public class DriveQuickstart {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY        = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        final List<String> SCOPES             = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
        final String JSON_PATH                = "my.json";
        final String USER                     = "user@domain.com";
        final String GROUP                    = "group@domain.com";
        final String DRIVE_ID                 = "bbb";

        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
            .fromStream(new FileInputStream(JSON_PATH))
            .createScoped(SCOPES)
            .createDelegated(USER);

        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,
                                          JSON_FACTORY,
                                          credential).build();

        DriveList result = service.drives().list().execute();
        System.out.println("drive list " + result);
        System.out.println("about to grant permission on id " + DRIVE_ID);

        service
            .permissions()
            .create(DRIVE_ID,
                    new Permission()
                    .setType("group")
                    .setRole("fileOrganizer")
                    .setEmailAddress(GROUP))
            .execute();
    }
}
```

As you can see from the output below, my code is able to list my two existing drives. The second one (with the id redacted to `bbb`) is the one I want to share with the group. When I use that same id in creating a Permission, the API responds with `File not found`:

```
drive list {"drives":[{"id":"aaa","kind":"drive#drive","name":"Manually Created Shared Drive"},
                      {"id":"bbb","kind":"drive#drive","name":"Shared Drive Created By Service Account"}],
            "kind":"drive#driveList"}

about to grant permission on id bbb

Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain"       : "global",
    "location"     : "fileId",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message"      : "File not found: bbb.",
    "reason"       : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "File not found: bbb."
}
  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:444)
  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1108)
  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:542)
  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:475)
  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:592)
  at DriveQuickstart.main(DriveQuickstart.java:63)
```

**Why does it say `File not found`?**

**Do I need to `setSupportsAllDrives(true)` in order to include *shared drives* as opposed to being limited to My Drive? If so where?**

The documentation says after June 1, 2020 all applications are assumed to support shared drives. I'm using the latest possible dependencies as of today (June 11), but all of these pre-date June 1. Here's the dependencies section from my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.30.9'
    compile 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev20200413-1.30.9'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
        service
            .permissions()
            .create(DRIVE_ID,
                    new Permission()
                    .setType("group")
                    .setRole("fileOrganizer")
                    .setEmailAddress(GROUP))
            .setSupportsAllDrives(true) // <---- add this here
            .execute();
```

As for the plan to assume all apps support shared drives, got this via email from Google Support:

> There was a plan to activate this by default as of June 1st, but this
>   is being reconsidered, and it will be necessary to add this parameter
>   to access shared drives for the foreseeable future. Our documentation
>   should be in the process of being updated.